# Align 4 images in cross like arrangement in HTML

Tags: html, css

What I am trying to do is to have 4 images align in a cross like pattern. I was thinking of using a table, but I do not want the corners, which will be while space to be the same as the image. And I want to be able to use different size images without having the page change if the image is a different dimension. I do not know how to approach this.

Below is an image of a rough sketch of what I am trying to do. One thing is that the images might be taller or longer.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what markup have you tried? there are probably a dozen ways to do this

Comment: It's one of the few cases where a table layout might be useful. Why can't you use a table-like layout? You simply do not place an image in the four corners. Also, will the top and bottom images be the same width? Will the left and right images be the same height?

Comment: @happymacarts I have not tried any markup, newish to html and this type of coding, and did not know how to approach it.

Comment: @Terry As for the table like structure, it has been a while since I used one. Won't the dimensions of the table change based the the images? Yes, in fact all 4 images will be the same width and height

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One solution would be to create invisible `div` elements that occupy the same height as your images, and inject them in the correct locations in the HTML:

```
div, img {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
}
```

See the fiddle with same image sizes [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/k7c23ssm/).

You can slightly modify this to use variable heights for your images by wrapping each row in its own `div`, then setting them height of each of those:

```
.top *, .middle *, .bottom * {
  float: left;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
}

.top, .bottom {
  height: 100px;
}

.middle {
  height: 200px;
}
```

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/Lom9cnx9/) for variable heights.

**Update:**

There's also the option to change the 'inset' of the middle row by giving the div a smaller width and adding margins to the two images in the middle row:

```
.middle div {
  width: 20%;
}

.middle img:nth-of-type(1) {
  margin-left: 6.5%
}

.middle img:nth-of-type(2) {
  margin-right: 6.5%
}
```

[Fiddle demonstrating this](https://jsfiddle.net/Obsidian_Age/LL2gn4jo/).

You can always play around with the width of the invisible div and the margins in order to get the desired output :)

Note that I've used widths that add up to 99% in these examples. You can get more specific if you'd like, but you'll never be able to reach 100% ;)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think that did it!! Thank you!!

Comment: You're more than welcome -- glad this worked for you :) Keep in mind that the images in each row will have to be the same height with this example, but you'd almost certainly want them to be anyway :)

Comment: Just asking, but what if I wanted to bring in the images on the sides to more in the center? Is there anyways to do that?

Comment: There sure is! I've updated my answer to show a third scenario demonstrating this :)

Comment: you are too awesome!!! thank you again. Can you just explain what .middle img:nth-of-type(2) means and would I have to add it to a class on my html?

Comment: Thanks haha. It's a very specific CSS selector. `.middle` refers to any DIV with class `middle`. `.middle img` refers to any image within a div that has the class `middle`. `img:nth-of-type(2)` refers specifically to the 2nd image. Combine that together, and `.middle img:nth-of-type(2)` refers specifically to the 2nd image within any div with the class `middle`. Hope that helps! There's a great breakdown of `nth-of-type` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-of-type.asp) :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133043/discussion-between-vlad-and-obsidian-age).

Answer (score 0):

**Here is another option using [Flex-box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox)**

this solution can accommodate images of different sizes

and you can read more about it [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
.wrapper {
  font-size: 150px;
  /* <-- adjust this to proportiantly scale everything */
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
img {
  width: 1em;
}
.container,
.row-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 3em;
}
.container {
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.row-container {
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/100x150">
    </div>

    <div class="row-container">
      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x120">
      </div>

      <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/170x110">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div>
      <img src="http://placehold.it/190x200">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And here is a table solution** 
which can also use images of varying size with radius corners

```css
td {text-align:center;vertical-align:center;}
td img {border-radius:4px;}
```

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/310x120"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/175x110"></td>
    <td></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/300x150"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><img src="http://placehold.it/280x100"></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```